# How configure Mysql 5.7 in docker compose?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have this in docker-compose.yml

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
        labels: mysql
        env: ubuntu
    networks:
      - backend
```

and

```
# cat ./mysql/conf.d/my-custom.conf 
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=1048573
query_cache_type=ON
query_cache_limit=256K
```

But anyway mysql have query_cache_type=OFF :(

How I can resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: MySQL 5.x is an old database at this point in time. I would strongly suggest to start a new application using MySQL 8.x or MariaDB 10.5. Unless, of course, there's a compelling reason to use such an old version of a database.

Comment: I have a one legacy project, and now I need to dokerize it...

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. I hope this will be useful to someone

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --query_cache_type=1 --query_cache_limit=10485760 --query_cache_size=1048576000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ...
```